# The address of const variable, C++

Tags: c++, constants

Recently I was rereading the Effective C++ by Scott Meyers (3-rd edition). And according to Meyers:
"Also, though good compilers won’t set
aside storage for const objects of integral types (unless you create a
pointer or reference to the object), sloppy compilers may, and you may
not be willing to set aside memory for such objects."
 Here in my code I can print the address of const variable, but I have not created a pointer or reference on it. I use Visual Studio 2012.

```
int main()
{
    const int x = 8;
    std::cout<<x<<" "<<&x<<std::endl;
}
```

The output is:
8 0015F9F4

Can anybody explain my the mismatch between the book and my code? Or I have somewhere mistaken?

Comment: Can you tell us what you are getting? And usually, if you compile in debug mode the constants won't be replaced in the code

Comment: You are still allowed to take the address of a const object. By taking the address you are most likely forcing the compiler to set aside some storage for it in the executable.

Comment: When you take the address you create a temporary pointer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By using the address-of operator on a variable, you are in fact creating a pointer. The pointer is a temporary object, not a declared variable, but it's very much there.

Furthermore there is a declared variable of pointer type that points to your variable: the argument to the overloaded `operator <<` that you used to print the pointer.

Answer (score 3):

```
     std::cout<<x<<" "<<&x<<std::endl;
```

You tried to get the address of the variable `x`,so the compiler thinks it is necessary to generate codes to `set aside storage for const objects`.

Answer (score 2):

By `&x`, you [ODR-used](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition#ODR-use) the variable, which makes allocating actual storage for `x` necessary.

Answer (score 2):

A good compiler (when using optimizations) will try to replace any compile-time constant by its value in your code to avoid making a memory access. However, if you do request the address of a constant (like you do) it can't do the optimization of not allocating memory to it.

However, one important thing to note is that it doesn't mean the research and replace wasn't done in your code. As you are not supposed to change the value of the constant, the compiler will assume it is safe to do a "research and replace" on it. If you do change the value with a `const_cast` you will get undefined behavior. It tends to work fine if you compile in debug but usually fails if your compiler optimizes the code.

Answer (score 2):

In C++,for basic data type constants, the compiler will put it in the symbol table without allocating storage space, and ADT(Abstract Data Type)/UDT(User Defined Type) const object will need to allocate storage space (large objects). There are some cases also need to allocate storage space, such as forcing declared as extern symbolic constants or take the address of symbolic constants,etc.